# How to assign a drawable to a widgets button

Tags: java, android, android-studio

hoping someone can help. Not sure if this is even possible but here goes.

I have an Android widget which consists of a single button. I want to programmatically set a drawable as the background. For example in a standard activity I might do...

```
Button mybutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.abutton);
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
gd.setCornerRadius(45);
gd.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF));
mybutton.setBackground(gd);
```

The reason I am trying to do this is to programmatically change the colour of the widget button to a colour the user picks but also maintain the rounded corners of the button as defined in the drawable above.

I've worked out I can change the colour of the widget button like so.

```
RemoteViews views;
views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.mylayout);
views.setInt(R.id.widgetbutton,"setBackgroundColor", Color.parseColor(widgethexcolor));
```

But this resets the button to its default rectangular shape without the rounded corners so I would prefer to make it a drawable.

Any ideas?

Thanks all!

Nat

Answer (score 0):

You could change the color by calling [`Drawable.setColorFilter(int color, PorterDuff.Mode mode)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setColorFilter(android.graphics.ColorFilter)) or [`Drawable.setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setColorFilter(android.graphics.ColorFilter)).  I think this approach will prevent you from losing the rounded corners.

Comment: Hello thanks for the response but I'm not sure I see how this can be applied to a RemoteView? I.e. the Widgets button? Thank you

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't understand your full question.  I'm not familiar with `RemoteViews` but from their documentation it seems their capabilities are limited, " and this class provides some basic operations for modifying the content of the inflated hierarchy" (source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews)