# How to create a custom button shape class

Tags: java, android

I'm editing this to explain that I was trying to create a button as part of a widget with rounded corners that could change its colour programmatically to any colour. When I do this currently using SetInt the default shape of the button changes back to a rectangle. It would appear that the usual ways of achieving this within an activity are not supported for RemoteViews so this question may be unanswerable. Thank you to Mike anyway for pointing this out.

I wonder if this is simple. I want to create a new button class - which is basically just a normal button with rounded corners. The reason for this is that I want to be able to programmatically change the background colour of the button to anything using...

```
mybutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parsecolor(somehexvalue));
```

without the button losing its shape (i.e. reverting to a rectangle).

I have created my button class and understand I need to overwrite the OnDraw method but don;t really understand how I then apply a custom shape at this point. Is this simple?

```
@RemoteView
public class custombutton extends       android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton {

    Paint paint = null;

    public custombutton(Context context) {
        super(context);

        paint = new Paint();
    }

    public custombutton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

public custombutton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)         {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        What do I need to do here to create a button with rounded corners???

    }

}
```

Thank you!!!!

Comment: If this is an attempt at a workaround for the issue you pose in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54120425), let me save you some time. You cannot use custom `View`s in `RemoteViews` – https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/#CreatingLayout. Only certain platform `View`s are supported, and, quoting that page, "Descendants of these classes are not supported".

Comment: @Regnodulous Are you want to apply Only Background color or drawable also at other place ?

Comment: Thank you all - yes Mike you are right. I was trying to make a new button class so that I can use it in my widget. I did not realise that RemoteViews did not support this. All I wanted to do was set a custom colour on a button which is part of a widget but I would prefer that button had rounded corners but it would seem this is near on impossible. Thanks again for the advice anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need of Customview for this.

Instead of setBackgroundColor, retrieve the background drawable when you need to change
 background, and set its color:

```
v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tags_rounded_corners);

GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) v.getBackground();
if (i % 2 == 0) {
  drawable.setColor(Color.RED);
} else {
  drawable.setColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Abhay - the problem is that I was trying to use remote views as part of a widget - not on a normal button in an activity so I'm not sure the above will work. As per Mikes answer I did not realise that RemoteViews does not support custom views. It seems that the methods supported by a button as part of a widget are very limited and it may not be possible to do what I want to do.  Thank you anyway for the advice.

Comment: @Regnodulous Interesting for me. Let me know if is this working in RemoteView or not.

Comment: Sorry no the setBackgroundResource cannot be used with a remoteview. :-)